# How to fix gcc warning: missing initializer for field of 'struct <anonymous>'?

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

I have a union typedef containing an anonymous struct. When trying to initialize it I always get a warning with gcc 4.9.2 (-Wall  -Wextra -pedantic) about missing initializers for fields. However it seems to work as expected. Is there something wrong with the way the variable is initialized below?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union {
  unsigned int raw;
  struct {
    unsigned short hue;
    unsigned char  saturation;
    unsigned char  value;
  };
} HSV;

int main() {
    HSV color = {.hue = 1, .saturation = 2, .value = 4};

    printf("hue: %d, saturation: %d, value: %d, raw: %08X\n", color.hue, color.saturation, color.value, color.raw);
}
```

When compiling gcc gives some warnings.

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 main.c 
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:13:2: warning: missing initializer for field 'saturation' of 'struct <anonymous>' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
  HSV color = {.hue =   1, .saturation = 2, .value = 4};
  ^
main.c:7:20: note: 'saturation' declared here
     unsigned char  saturation;
                    ^
main.c:13:2: warning: missing initializer for field 'value' of 'struct <anonymous>' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
  HSV color = {.hue =   1, .saturation = 2, .value = 4};
  ^
main.c:8:20: note: 'value' declared here
     unsigned char  value;
                    ^
$ ./a.out 
hue: 1, saturation: 2, value: 4, raw: 04020001
```

Comment: No warnings in GCC 5.x.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? I am seeing exact same error.

Comment: @PunitSoni: no. I moved to gcc 5 where it's not happening as Dúthomhas mentioned. So seems it's a gcc bug...